# OSGi - Is it possible to override a bundle's classes using a fragment?

Tags: osgi, fragment, bundle

A class is in fragment bundle.

Can this class override or extends host bundle for same name class?

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: example

Bundle-SymbolicName: example.fragment
Fragment-Host: example;
```

can anyone give me Some of Fragment bundle examples?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's explicitly stated in the OSGi specification that resources (including classfiles) will be  first looked up in the host bundle, and only if not found there will any fragment bundles be consulted.

If you use Declarative Services you can override a service by redeclaring it in a fragment with a higher priority than the host.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible but only if the host bundle prepared itself by putting an element at the start of its Bundle-Classpath that a later fragment can populate.

Comment: Crap, that would solve *severe* headaches for me - do you have any handy reference?

Comment: See 3.9.1 Bundle-Classpath in the Core spec.

Comment: Link to [3.9.1 Bundle Class Path](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/7.0.0/framework.module.html#framework.module.bundleclasspath) in the Core spec.